# Does the free Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit manipulate any configuration of servers it probes?

Tags: azure

Is there any official statement that the [Microsoft Assessment and Planning (MAP) Toolkit](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb977556.aspx) does NOT manipulate any configuration of servers it probes or make any other changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I received the following paraphrased answer from MAP Toolkit Support after I wrote to them -

MAP Toolkit gathers data using WMI Technology. It does not manipulate any configuration on existing server.

MAP Toolkit is fully safe for any environment. It slightly affects performance

Related links -

- [FAQ](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1643.microsoft-assessment-and-planning-toolkit-frequently-asked-questions.aspx)
- [How to use MAP](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/17804.how-to-use-the-map-toolkit.aspx)
- [Case studies](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/solutionaccelerators/dd537566)